# How to load data into hive by using Java Program?

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hadoop2

I've tried loading data into hive with command line way. Its working fine with this way.

Now I want to load data through Java. So for this purpose I've written code & I'm able create tables,databases,inserting values into it, but while using load command it not working.

```
private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
        private static String databaseURL = "jdbc:hive2://server_name:10001/test";
        private static String userName = "<hadoop_user";
        private static String password = "<password>";
        private static Connection con = null;
        private final static Logger log = 
        private static String dbName="db_name",
                tableName="table_name",
                path = "";
private  void loadData(String path,String tableName) {

            // create statement
            Statement stmt;
            try {
                stmt = con.createStatement();
                String sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'file:/"+path+ "' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE "+tableName+"";
                System.out.println("Load Data into  successful"+sql);
                stmt.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'file:/"+path+ "' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE "+tableName+"");



                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Giving This Issue,

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.plugin.HiveAccessControlException: Permission denied: Principal [name=hadoop, type=USER] does not have following privileges for operation LOAD [[SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, OBJECT OWNERSHIP] on Object [type=LOCAL_URI, name=file:/D:/DTCC/Pig/Dummy_data_Main.tsv]]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.plugin.sqlstd.SQLAuthorizationUtils.assertNoDeniedPermissions(SQLAuthorizationUtils.java:414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.plugin.sqlstd.SQLStdHiveAuthorizationValidator.checkPrivileges(SQLStdHiveAuthorizationValidator.java:96)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.plugin.HiveAuthorizerImpl.checkPrivileges(HiveAuthorizerImpl.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.doAuthorizationV2(Driver.java:725)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.doAuthorization(Driver.java:518)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1067)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileAndRespond(Driver.java:1061)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.prepare(SQLOperation.java:100)
    ... 15 more
```

What I tried:
1) I give all permission to hadoop user on HDFS path of table
2) I give all permission to table such as SELECT, INSERT, DELETE

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31825086/mismatched-input-row-expecting-eof-error-while-creating-hive-table
please refer to the above question and answer me

Answer (score 1):

Make sure for the following -

- if you have kerberos security setup, don't forget to use kinit
- User "hadoop" should have access to write on the folder (hive table location). -- For any HDFS path that you are changing the permission, simply "change permission" or "chmod" command would not work. You need to run "hdfs dfs -setfacl -R -m user::rwx ".
- Also, make sure this table location has the same parent directory as it is for other tables that you are successfully able to create. [Some times, admin can restrict to create table in other location ].